# get data in object - SimpleXML

Tags: php, xml, oop

So I got a simple function that works, but I'm trying to evolve my experince wtih OOP and try to make sure I can use my code without having to edit everything.

Here is my simple function

```
$xmlfeed = file_get_contents('/forum/syndication.php?limit=3');

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlfeed);
$result = $xml->xpath('channel/item/title');

while(list( , $node) = each($result)) {
    echo $node;
}
```

Now so far I got to this point:

```
class ForumFeed {
    private function getXMLFeeds($feed = 'all'){
        /*
            Fetch the XML feeds
         */
        $globalFeedXML = file_get_contents('/forum/syndication.php?limit=3');
        $newsFeedXML = file_get_contents('/forum/syndication.php?fid=4&limit=3');

        /*
            Turn feed strings into actual objects
         */
        $globalFeed = new SimpleXMLElement($globalFeedXML);
        $newsFeed = new SimpleXMLElement($newsFeedXML);

            /*
                Return requested feed
             */
            if ($feed == 'news') {
                return $newsFeed;
            } else if ($feed == 'all') {
                return $globalFeed;
            } else {
                return false;
            }

    }
    public function formatFeeds($feed) {
        /*
            Format Feeds for displayable content..
            For now we're only interested in the titles of each feed
         */
        $getFeed = $this->getXMLFeeds($feed);

        return $getFeed->xpath('channel/item/title');
    }
}

$feeds = new ForumFeed();
```

However when trying to `echo $feeds->formatFeeds('all');` it doesn't return anything.  The results is blank.

What am I doing wrong?

`var_dump($feeds->formatFeeds('all'));` returns

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  object(SimpleXMLElement)#3 (0) {
  }
  [1]=>
  object(SimpleXMLElement)#4 (0) {
  }
  [2]=>
  object(SimpleXMLElement)#5 (0) {
  }
}
```

Comment: please specify the language in the tags

Comment: You try to echo an array, that normally gives you `"Array"` (as string). See as well: http://php.net/language.types.string#language.types.string.casting - Also try to isolate your problem. It's never the whole script. So put your script aside for a moment, and create a new one just for the question you want to ask here with as little code as necessary to demonstrate the issue. Also try to understand your own, what happens and why it happens.

Answer (score 1):

According to PHPs documentation SimpleXMLElement::xpath returns an array of SimpleXMLElements or false on error. Maybe `var_dump($feeds->formatFeeds('all'));` prints something you then can use to debug.

Edit: The XPath query returns results, so probably there is a logical error in your query or the returned elements don't have content.

Comment: Does it work if you use the XPath-Query "//channel/item/title" instead?